# Unable to create session in .NET Razor Page

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I have this code which run without error

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString(sessionStatus, "Done");
```

But, when I put a breakpoint at this line (above) and try to read it with code below in the watch window, the value is null in it.

```
HttpContext.Session.GetString("sessionStatus")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad. Found the problem already.

```
 HttpContext.Session.SetString("sessionStatus", "Done");
```